# What happens if I remove a fork with forks from Github?

Tags: git, github

Quite often I fix small issues I come across in projects on Github. Whenever I do this a fork is created in my repository. Over time this summed up in more than 100 forked projects in my Github account.

Today I wanted to clean any unused forked project from my account. Now I found 12 projects left forked from my fork by others. None of them received pull-requests.

What happens to the forks of my fork if I delete my fork? Will they get "orphaned" or linked back to the original source of my fork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[What happens to forks when a repository is deleted or changes visibility?](https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility/):

## Deleting a private repository

When you delete a private repository, all of its private forks are also deleted.

## Deleting a public repository

When you delete a public repository, one of the existing public forks is chosen to be the new parent repository. All other repositories are forked off of this new parent and subsequent pull requests go to this new parent.

Comment: Does the new parent have the original repo as its parent?

Comment: Repositories closer to the root are not changed at all, they continue to have relations they have had before a fork removed.

Comment: so if Original->F1->F2 exists and F1 is deleted it becomes Original->F2?

Comment: Or `Original->F3->F2`. But you're asking a different question. In situation `Original->F1->F2->F3` if `F2` was deleted the new relations graph becomes `Original->F1->F4->F3` or `Original->F1->F3` but the relation of `F1` is not changed.